# Joining split list into a list

Tags: python, string, list, join, split

I'm trying to take a split up list and join them into another list. For example, I have this list:

```
['T', 'e', 's', 't', '\n', 'List', '\n']
```

Now I want to join these so it looks like

```
['Test', 'List']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What are the rules?  One letter strings are combined?  '\n' is simply ignored?  Or is '\n' the end of a string?

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid that your question is a little underspecified, as [S. Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott) comments, but it looks as if you just want to join all the strings together and then split where there are newlines - the following works for your example, and could be easily modified for other requirements:

```
>>>> ''.join(['T', 'e', 's', 't', '\n', 'List', '\n']).splitlines()
['Test', 'List']
```

Answer (score 4):

string joining is an amazing thing

```
l = ['T', 'e', 's', 't', '\n', 'List', '\n']
"".join(l).split('\n')
```

Works by taking a "" string, creating a larger string by appending all of l to it giving "Test\nList\n". Then splitting on end of line giving ["Test", "List"]

Comment: +1 because splitting on '\n' is more explicit in this case than splitting with splitlines()